# Porous Boundary

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, boundary

I just set up a boundary for my game which seems to be working alright until it is really forced, as in I make my character run towards it for several seconds, and then my character will just go straight through. Any explanations for this and how I can fix it?

edit:
here is the code for my boundary

```
    func createSceneContents() {
         self.backgroundColor = .black
         self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
                }

    createSceneContents()
        ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: ship.size)
        ship.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        ship.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        ship.name = "ship"
        ship.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ship
        ship.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ship
```

Comment: I too run into this issue with edge loops and have yet to find a fix.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting precise collision detection for your `ship`:

`ship.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true`

You also might consider adding a physics category to the boundary.